# Больше чем два предложения у вставки с тире — так можно?

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, можно ли в тиреобразной вставке писать больше чем два предложения? В РАН написано, что при больших вставках нужно использовать скобкообразную вставку, но, однако, там не написано, что если всего два-три предложения, то тире – это ошибка, и только ошибка.

`Я весь день – я что, кстати, вы делали? Могу поспорить, что в лесок ходили, – сидел на стуле.`

`Я весь день – я что, кстати, вы делали? Могу поспорить, что в лесок ходили. Не так ли это, мэм? – сидел на стуле.`

Comment: *Тиреобразная вставка* это что за фрукт?

Comment: Я думаю, что скобки применяются при сложной СТРУКТУРЕ,  когда вставка содержит несколько отдельных предложений (они начинаются с прописной буквы). Тире из-за этих прописных букв не подойдет.

Comment: Нет, и в скобках тоже не надо. У предложения не должно быть два окончания. Просто Булгаков намудрил, а Лопатин это подхватил. У Розенталя такого нет, потому что Розенталь гораздо умнее.